# jQuery, slide-in text

Tags: jquery, animation

I am new to jQuery. How can I make some text slide in?  I tried this and 1) it does not work, and 2) I might prefer to have it slide in from the side

```
$("#someId").html("hello").slideDown('slow');
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's hard to tell what's wrong without more information, since there are several possible points where things can go wrong.  Here are some possibilities:

1. If the element is already showing, it won't animate.
2. If the jquery selection ends up not picking up any elements, you won't see anything either.  Is there an element with the id 'someId' in your DOM tree?

Here's an example of a use of slideDown:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
   <head>
     <script src="jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
     <script type="text/javascript">
         $(document).ready(
             function() {
                 $("#someId").hide();
                 $("#someId").html("hello").slideDown('slow');
         });
     </script>
  </head>
  <body>
      <div id="someId"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: dyoo, Thanks for this example; I can see it works and more specifically I see that the html...slidedown syntax works as well.  I think my mistake was not placing the line of code within the document...ready...function.  A curious thing though is that the word "hello" is injected into the html, but the slidedown function does Not work.  I was actually redoing an old script I wrote in JavaScript where this statement is within an if/else.  I am thinking I have to move the entire if/else and maybe the whole script within document...ready...function.

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#someId").html("hello").show('slide');
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/6LB8M/

Answer (score 1):

Check out the animate function, it will give you much more flexibility:

http://api.jquery.com/animate/

You'll want to be modifying either the margin or the x / y position...something like this:

```
$('#someID').html("hello").animate({
  left: '+=50',
}, 1000, function() {
  // Animation complete.
});
```

This means that `#someID` will have an animation applied in which the elements position on the x axis will be increased by 50 pixels, and it will happen over 1 second.

Answer (score 1):

1 - Perhaps it needs to be hidden beforehand? i.e.:

```
#someId { display: none }
```

2 - You can animate the width of the container. So if your container has zero width, animate it to 250 pixels in width (or whatever).

```
$('#someId').animate({
    width: '250',
}, 5000, function() {
    // Animation complete.
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/animate/

Comment: yes - if you put a hide() before your slidedown, it will work

Answer (score 1):

CSS:

```
#someId

{
    width:100px;
    margin-left:-100px;
}
```

jQuery

```
$('div').animate({marginLeft:"0"},1500);
```

See it here http://jsfiddle.net/v8XFn/

Answer (score 1):

This can work nicely.

```
$(".inner").mouseover(function(){
  $(".inner").animate({"marginLeft": "-=100px"}, "slow");
});

$(".inner").mouseout(function(){
  $(".inner").animate({"marginLeft": "+=100px"}, "slow");
});
```

See it at work here:   **http://jsfiddle.net/R4Xyd/5/**

Answer (score 0):

You can animate the position. You should get something like this:

html:

```
<p id="animated_text">text to be animated</p>
```

css:

```
p {
position: abosulte;
left: 0;
}
```

jquery:

```
$("#animated_text").animate({'left': '+=200'}, 1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Get the jQuery-easing plugin and add it to your file

```
<script src="script/jquery.easing.1.3.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
--and do this--
$('#yourDiv').delay(3000).effect('slide', { direction: "right" });
```